# databetween two dates from usercontrol

Tags: c#

In my form i made a user control of label textbox datepicker 
in this form i put a datagrid in which i want data between two dates as i click submit button..my code is:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IRIS-CSG-174;Initial Catalog=library_system;Integrated Security=True");
                cs.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between'" +userControl11.Text+ "'" + "and'" + userControl12.Text + "'", cs);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "lib_issue_details");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", ds, "lib_issue_details"));

                cs.Close();


            }
```

But this code is not giving data from database,it only gives database columns name as I select from two dates from datepicker as I want data beween two dates.

Comment: I had similar problem with date type.

Comment: If you run the SELECT statement in SQL Manager does it return data back to you?

Comment: Maybe the data is simply empty.. add break point and see what is the value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` - probably it will be 0.

Comment: First of all, you'll want to fix that SQL injection vulnerability.  String-concatenated queries are bad from both a security and a performance perspective.  Second, what is the actual query being generated and what does it return when you manually run it on the database?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this will fix your sql injection, secondly it will remove time constraints and you don't have to create a binding so I've removed that line and added a comment

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IRIS-CSG-174;Initial Catalog=library_system;Integrated Security=True"); 
        cs.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where CAST(book_issue_on AS Date) between CAST(@StartDate AS Date) and CAST(@EndDate AS Date)", cs);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", dateTimePicker1.Text)); //If this is a datetimepicker it would be better to use: dateTimePicker1.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", dateTimePicker1.Text)); //If this is a datetimepicker it would be better to use: dateTimePicker1.Value

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(ds, "lib_issue_details"); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 

//By Default it will infer the columns from your dataset, otherwise create the columns on your designer
//dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", ds, "lib_issue_details"));
cs.Close();
```